# Global button not showing in some views - MVC AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, view

I'm writing a program that simulates a travel experience where a user can type in a city name in a view (writing the program in MVC style) and then the user gets "transported" to a view that represents the city with pictures, information etc.

As said before, the program is written in MVC and my main problem is the following:

I made a global button (not sure if this is the rigth definition, but technically the button should appear in every view i want it too) that if clicked brings the user back to the start view (where user can type in a new city name etc).

My problem is that the button only appears in one of the views (they are atm completely similar in code apart from the difference in names) and not in the others.

This is the code that creates the button (which relies on a separate class that gives it size etc) in my Main.as:

```
    private function initMVC():void{

        goBackButton = new Button("Back");
        goBackButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goBackButtonHandler);

        goToDestinationButton = new Button("");
        goToDestinationButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToDestionationButtonHandler);

        // Create the MODEL
        _model = new Model();

        // Create the CONTROLLERs which holds a reference of the MODEL
        _controller1 = new Controller1(_model);
        _controller2 = new Controller2(_model);

        // Create the VIEWs which holds references of both MODEL and CONTROLLER
        _view1 = new startView(_model, _controller1, goToDestinationButton);
        _view2 = new parisView(_model, _controller2, goBackButton);
        _view3 = new berlinView(_model, _controller2, goBackButton);
        _view4 = new copenhagenView(_model, _controller2, goBackButton);

        //add starting VIEW to Stage
        this.addChild(_view1);
    }

    private function goBackButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {               
        this.removeChildAt(0);
        this.addChild(_view1);
    }
    private function goToDestionationButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {               
        if (_model.name == "PARIS"){
        trace("Switching to View: Paris");
        this.removeChildAt(0);
        this.addChild(_view2);
        }
        else if (_model.name == "BERLIN"){
        trace("Switching to View: Berlin");
        this.removeChildAt(0);
        this.addChild(_view3);
        }
        else if (_model.name == "COPENHAGEN"){
        trace("Switching to View: Copenhagen");
        this.removeChildAt(0);
        this.addChild(_view4);
        }
        else{
        trace("We do not have that destination in our system yet, come back later.");
        }
```

Here is an example of one of the views created to represent a city:

```
public class berlinView extends Sprite
{
    private var _navButton:Button;
    private var _model:Model;
    private var _controller:Controller2
    private var nametextField:TextField;

    public function berlinView(model:Model, controller:Controller2, navigationButton:Button)
    {
        _model= model;
        _controller = controller

        var atextField:TextField = new TextField();
        atextField.text = "This is Berlin";
        this.addChild(atextField);

        _navButton = navigationButton;
        _navButton.x = 100;
        _navButton.y = 100;
        this.addChild(_navButton);
    }
}
```

}

I might have overlooked something very simple or basic since it's my first "real" AS3 program. Hope someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the button is instantiated only once but you call `addChild` on every view, so it will only be added to the last created view : `_view4`

You should change your views constructor like that:

```
public function berlinView(model:Model, controller:Controller2, navigationButton:Button)
{
    _model= model;
    _controller = controller

    var atextField:TextField = new TextField();
    atextField.text = "This is Berlin";
    this.addChild(atextField);

    _navButton = navigationButton;
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}
```

Then, only add the button when the view is displayed ie when it is added to stage:

```
private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
{
   _navButton.x = 100;
   _navButton.y = 100;
   this.addChild(_navButton);
}
```